# C++: Problem of Korean alphabet encoding in text file write process with std::ofstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

I have a code for save the log as a text file.

It usually works well, but I found a case where doesn't work:

> {Id": "testman", "ip": "192.168.1.1", "target": "?뚯뒪??exe", "desc": "?덈뀞諛⑷??뚯슂"}

My code is a simple logic that saves the log string as a text file.

My code was works well when log is English, but there is a problem when log is Korean language.

After checking through various experiments, it was confirmed that Korean language would not problem if the file could be saved as utf-8 format.

[image]

I think, if Korean language is included in log string, c++ is basically saved as ANSI format.

[image]

This is my c++ code:

```
string logfilePath = {path};
log = "{\Id\": \"testman\", \"ip\": \"192.168.1.1\", \"target\": \"테스트.exe\", \"desc\": \"안녕방가워요\"}";

ofstream output(logFilePath, ios::app);
output << log << endl;
output.close();
```

Is there a way to save log files as uft-8 or any other good way?

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `UTF-8` in `File->Advanced Save Options`.
[image]

[image]

If you do not find it, you could add `Advanced Save Options` in `Tools->Customize->Commands->Add Command..->File`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**TDLR:** write 0xefbbbf (3-bytes UTF-8 BOM) in the beginning of the file before writing out your string.

One of the hints that text viewer software use to determine if the file should be shown in the Unicode format is something called the Byte Order Marker (or BOM for short). It is basically a series of bytes in the beginning of a stream of text that specifies the encoding and endianness of the text string. For UTF-8 it is these three bytes 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF.

You can experiment with this by opening notepad, writing a single character and saving file in the ANSI format. Then look at the size of file in bytes. It will be 1 byte. Now open the file and save it in UTF-8 and look at the size of file again. It will 4 bytes that is three bytes for the BOM and one byte for the single character you put in there. You can confirm this by viewing both files in some hex editor.

That being said, you may need to insert these bytes to your files before writing your string to them. So why UTF-8? you may ask, well, it depends on the encoding the original string is encoded in (your `std::string log`) which in this case it is an string literal written in a source file whose encoding is (most likely) UTF-8. Therefor the bytes that build up the string are made according to this encoding and are put into your executable.
note that `std::string` can contain Unicode string, it just can't make sense of it. For example it reports its length wrong. But it can be used to carry Unicode string around fine.